# How to add response headers in Internet explorer using the passthru app

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++

I have managed to modify an existing response header by overriding                                          IWinInetHttpInfo::QueryInfo. However, I don't manage to find a way to add a response header that does not exist in the current response. Does anyone know how to do that?

This is an example how to modify an existing CORS header (the question is how to add the CORS header if it does not exist):

```
   inline STDMETHODIMP IInternetProtocolImpl::QueryInfo(
   /* [in] */ DWORD dwOption,
   /* [in, out] */ LPVOID pBuffer,
   /* [in, out] */ DWORD *pcbBuf,
   /* [in, out] */ DWORD *pdwFlags,
   /* [in, out] */ DWORD *pdwReserved)
   {
          ATLASSERT(m_spWinInetHttpInfo  != 0);

          char* buf = new char[*pcbBuf];
          memcpy(buf,pBuffer,*pcbBuf);
          char* res = strstr(buf, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"); 
          delete[] buf;
          buf = NULL;

          HRESULT hr =  m_spWinInetHttpInfo ? m_spWinInetHttpInfo->QueryInfo(dwOption, pBuffer, pcbBuf, pdwFlags, pdwReserved) : E_UNEXPECTED;

          if(res != NULL) // its CORS!!!
          {
                 *((char*)pBuffer) = '*';
                 *((char*)pBuffer + 1) = '\0';
                 *pcbBuf = 1;
          }
          return hr;
   }
```

Comment: This code should largely work regardless of whether the header exists or not. Just make sure to return `S_OK` when reporting your data - the real protocol probably returns an error when the header is missing, and you blindly forward that.

Comment: Thank you Igor, it's finally working. However, i'm trying to modify/add the content-disposition and it seems that QueryInfo is not being called with this header (even when it exists). Any idea why or how can i modify/add the content-disposition header?

Comment: This particular piece of data is pushed, not pulled. Call `InternetProtocolSink::ReportProgress(BINDSTATUS_CONTENTDISPOSITIONATTACH)`

Comment: Thanks again Igor. Do you happen to know why QueryInfo is not being called for POST requests? Any other way to add HTTP response headers for POST requests?

Comment: `QueryInfo` is not being called because the client doesn't care about any information it can provide, I suppose. What headers, specifically, do you want to add? Some of them have dedicated notifications - see e,g, the aforementioned `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: I'm trying to add/modify Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Can you think of a way to do it for POST requests?

Comment: Are these CORS requests to begin with? As in, do they have `Origin:` request header? Otherwise, the browser would have no reason to check response headers. If they are indeed CORS requests, then I would have expected the browser to use `IWinInetHttpInfo::QueryInfo`, as I know of no other way to obtain arbitrary headers. Note also that your `if(res != NULL)` check is always true; not sure what you are trying to do here.